# Python: pass function as argument, evaluate with try/except and return result

Tags: python, h2o

I'm currently trying to extract model result information from H2O in Python.

For context, I have something along the following lines:

```
model = H2ODeepLearningEstimator(...)
model.train()
```

After the model is trained, I can call up the various model metrics. However, some metric will only be generated depending on the type of model.

So for example, I could call `model.mse(valid=True)` and it will return a value. but if I call `model.aic(valid=True)` it will throw and exception if AIC was not generated. This is a problem because I need to generate a function that writes all generated metrics to a HIVE table. If the metric has not been generated and calling it throws an except, we'll simply write NULL to hive.

So, I've tried to do the following:

```
param=None
try:
    param=tryParam(model.aic())
except:
    pass
print(param)
```

This will correctly return `None` for the AIC value

However, I need to do this for every parameter, so would prefer to wrap a generic function around it. For example, I would like to pass the function `model.aic()` as a parameter to a function called `tryParam`, which then evaluates it and catches any expections that occur. Such as:

```
def tryParam(getParam):
    try:
        return getParam
    except:   
        return None

tryParam(model.aic())
tryParam(model.mse())
tryParam(model.mae())
etc.
```

However, this does not work. When I call `tryParam(model.aic())` the exception is raised and the program stops. It would seem to me that the parameter is being evaluated before it is passed to `tryParam` (hence triggering the exception before the code to handle it is actually called). This is only a guess though.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: As a side note, you may want to only catch expected exception - a catch-all except clause can hide other issues, specially when it just silences and ignores the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the function inside `tryParam` with any args or kwargs passed.

```
def tryParam(getParam, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return getParam(*args, **kwargs)
    except:   
        return None
```

Then pass the function itself rather than calling it, along with any args or kwargs.

```
tryParam(model.aic, valid=True)
```

Comment: Partly solves it but brought me on the right track! (I left out part of the requirement though, which is that model.aic needs to be called with some keyword argments as well). Instead of just passing getParam, I need to also pass **kwargs. Then return getParam(**kwargs).

Finally call tryParam(model.aic, "valid=True").

Answer (score 1):

I would try to do this way:

```
def tryParam(obj, methodName):
    method = getattr(obj, methodName, None)
    if method is not None:
        return method()
```

Then I can use like:

```
model = H2ODeepLearningEstimator(...)
model.train()

aic = tryParam(model, 'aic')
mse = tryParam(model, 'mse')
mae = tryParam(model, 'mae')
```

[Repl.it example here](https://repl.it/KVxc/0)